# Use both parents methods in the same method

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have a class called **Cyborg** and it inherits from another two classes: **Human** and **Robot**.
Supposing the two parents have their own method **Talk()**, can I call these two methods from the **Cyborg** child? For example:

```
class Cyborg(Human, Robot):
    def Talk(self):
        human_properties = Human.Talk()
        robot_properties = Robot.Talk()
        return human_properties + robot_properties
```

The super() method do not resolve that problem.

Comment: Can you show the (minimal) definitions of `Robot` and `Human`?

Comment: You must explicitly pass `self` when you call the methods with the class: `Human.talk(self)` and `Robot.talk(self)` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `super()` you will pick up the first method of the same name up the MRO chain, but not both (unless the picked up method calls `super()` on its own). If you want to pick them both you'll have to call them manually and explicitly pass the `self` reference:

```
class Cyborg(Human, Robot):
    def Talk(self):
        human_properties = Human.Talk(self)
        robot_properties = Robot.Talk(self)
        return human_properties + robot_properties
```

I'd advise against multiple inheritance anyway - while nifty and useful, and in very rare cases irreplaceable, it comes with so many pitfalls that dealing with it is just not worth it...

Answer (score 2):

If you implement your inheritance graph correctly, this can be done with `super`. For this to work, both `Human` and `Robot` need a common base class that can `Talk`.

```
class Thing:
    def Talk(self):
        # Things don't talk, but some more complex things may
        return ''

class Robot(Thing):
    def Talk(self):
        return 'I am a computer!\n' + super().Talk()

class Human(Thing):
    def Talk(self):
        return 'I am an organic being!\n' + super().Talk()

class Cyborg(Human, Robot):
    def Talk(self):
        return super().Talk()
```

Here is a talking example.

```
>>> Cyborg().Talk()
I am an organic being!
I am a computer!

>>> Robot().Talk()
I am a computer!

>>> Human().Talk()
I am an organic being!
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this approach in comparison to the @zwer response? Create an unnecessary base class only to deal with it is a good idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The advantage of using super is maintainability. Suppose you have multiple methods that need to call methods from Human and Robot and that you add another inheritance to your class. You then have to update every single method that did explicit calls. With super, this is done automatically.

Comment: Oh right, I agree with you. And how can I return some content from Human and Robot to be printed in Cyborg child?

Comment: @norogino The method `super().Talk` can return as would any method, so you can use it to return a string. I added return values as example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of treating `Talk` as a method, implement it as a `classmethod`, thus eliminating the need to inherit in the first place:

```
class Human:
   @classmethod
   def Talk(cls, *args):
      return 

class Robot:
  @classmethod
   def Talk(cls, *args):
      return

class Cyborg:
  def Talk(self):
     return Human.Talk() + Robot.Talk()
```

Comment: or indeed a `staticmethod`.